# Selecting datetime range in MultiIndexed dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the problem:

I want to select the dataframe (say, `df3`) with each index1 in df1 to be in the range between `d_reach` and `d_start` in `df2`,

Below is the code to generate samples:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

index1 = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 1), periods = 1000, freq = "3min")

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(1000), index = index1, columns = ['r'])

d_start = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 1), periods = 500, freq = "5min")

d_reach = d_start + timedelta(seconds = np.random.randint(low = 4, high = 6))

value = {'id3': np.tile([0,1], 250)}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(value, index = [d_start,d_reach])

df2.index.names = ['d_start','d_reach']
```

`df2` is MultiIndexed.

The expected ouput of df3 should be:

```
2021-01-01 01:07:00     0.011026

2021-01-01 01:10:00     0.423813
...
```

here `index1` in `df1` `2021-01-01 01:07:00 >= 2021-01-01 01:06:05` which is one of the `d_reach` in `df2`
and the next `index1` in `df1` `2021-01-01 01:10:00 < 2021-01-01 01:11:00` which is the next `d_start` in `df2`

Below is the code I tried but failed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df1.index:
    df = df.append(df1.loc[i])
    for idx1, idx2 in zip(df2.index.get_level_values(0).tolist(), 
    df2.index.get_level_values(1).tolist())
    if i >= idx1 and i <= idx2
```

Really appreciate any advice as to find `df3` in Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select the dataframe (say, df3) with each index1 in df1 to be in the range between d_reach and d_start in df2,

here is one way to cross join then find the matches and filter them out :

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index() , how='cross', on=None)
result = mdf.loc[mdf['index'].between(mdf['d_start'], mdf['d_reach']),['index','r']].set_index('index')
print(result.head())
```

output:

```
>>>
                            r
index                        
2021-01-01 01:01:00  0.415163
2021-01-01 01:16:00  0.729592
2021-01-01 01:31:00  0.411244
2021-01-01 01:46:00  0.524753
2021-01-01 02:01:00  0.105035
```

That's going to be memory intensive though, another way is to load your dataframes into an in-memory database and join them based on the condition and load the result back to your result dataframe, you will find a lot of samples on that method online.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! The result is not correct because it should start with '2021-01-01 01:07:00' not '2021-01-01 01:01:00'. And I got the 'MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False'

Comment: @JianXu are you cross joining? (` how='cross',`) and why it should start from 01:07 ?

Comment: yes, I use how = 'cross'. you can find the detailed info from my question because "2021-01-01 01:07:00 >= 2021-01-01 01:06:05 which is one of the d_reach in df2 and the next index1 in df1 2021-01-01 01:10:00 < 2021-01-01 01:11:00 which is the next d_start in df2". it's very complicated.

Comment: the DatetimeIndex is fixed although the 'r' or 'id3' values are randomly generated. So it must start with '2021-01-01 01:07:00'

Comment: ok , sorry but stll this is doing what you asked : `I want to select the dataframe (say, df3) with each index1 in df1 to be in the range between d_reach and d_start in df2,`

Comment: thanks, but the current answer is not what i want. The expected ouput of df3 should start with '2021-01-01 01:07:00'.